# Typescript returning 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRowIndex')

Tags: excel, typescript

I have a very simple script that I'm trying to run, and the part that I'm stuck is essentially the Vlookup part, searching the value from one table to another, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out how to do it. Here is the snippet that I'm having problem.

```
function performLookup(inputString: string, lookupRangeAddress: ExcelScript.Range): string {
    
    let result = '';

    let values = lookupRangeAddress.getValues();

    for (let i = 0; i < inputString.length; i += 36) {
        
        const substring = inputString.substr(i, 36);

        //This line is the one returning with problems. It says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRowIndex')
        let lookupValue = lookupRangeAddress.find(substring, {completeMatch: false}).getRowIndex();

        //const clc = lookupCell.getColumnIndex();
        //let rlc = lookupValue.getRowIndex();



        
        if (lookupValue !== undefined) {
            result += workbook.getWorksheet("Ids").getTable("UserIds").getRange().getCell(lookupValue, 2) + ', ';
        }
    }

    
    if (result.endsWith(', ')) {
        result = result.slice(0, -2);
    }

    return result;
    
}
```

I'm using Excel's script function. I don't know why it won't go through, but essentially all it needs to do is split a string into chunks of 36 characters, search for those, concatenate them and return the value concatenated. The rest of the script I do in a separate function.

Thank you in advance for all the support, I'm very new to this TypeScript word so if you could provide an answer with an explanation that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, obviously your `.find()` doesn't find the value and returns `undefinded`. Are you sure, the searchstring is found?

Comment: Yes, if I don’t use the getRow command, it returns [object] or simply the text that I’m searching for. In fact, it even splits the strings if it is a large one as it should. My issue is that I need this code to search for something on column A and return the value in the same row in column B